# What is the alternate to hex values in java

Tags: java, android, pointers, hex

how do i use hex value replacement in my code
and also is there any issues while using the hex values, regarding the Pointer from the main activity?

such errors like `NullPointerExceptions` ...

Comment: You mean, like, `0x1234`?

Comment: yes like `0x99999` ...

Comment: What do you mean by "replacement in my code" exactly?

Comment: like this i used in my code, and my code not working properly, so i thought these hex values are creating some kind of `NullPointerException`
`intent.addFlags(0x80000);`

Comment: Perhaps `intent` is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the prefix **0x** for variables to specify that they're hex values, e.g:

```
int x = 0x12F8
```

In Java you do not have to set pointers, therefore there can be no NullPointerExceptions from simply assigning a variable a hex value.